# using jquery to add an asterisk to all form fields with data-required=true

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-element, parsley.js

I was using this to add a asterisk from the fontawesome library to all form fields who had 'required' as a pseudo element (in a Twitter bootstrap form):

Field example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" 
    data-required="true" 
    data-error-message="Please enter your firstname" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(":required")
    .closest(".control-group")
    .children("label")
    .prepend("<i class='icon-asterisk'></i> ");
```

This works fine but I now moved to [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org) to validate my form inputs. Parsley uses data-required='true' as a pseude element. I am not really into pseudo selectors right now. How do I change my jquery to do the trick again?

Comment: a few years late, but why not just modify the html and add the label?

Comment: Because I like to keep my forms as basic as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work.

```
$( 'input[data-required="true"]' )
        .closest(".control-group")
        .children("label")
        .prepend("<i class='icon-asterisk'></i> ");
```

Link to the [Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: This is it, thanks! And thanks for pointing me to the right documentation too. I was defenitely looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: With later versions of jQuery I would recommend changing the selector to `:input`, or dropping `input` altogether (leaving `$('[data-required="true"]')`) -- this would cover more elements and kind of future-proof this solution.